# Keepass - password paranoia

Tags: authentication, passwords

How do I know that the Keepass app isn't behind the scenes at some point sending my master password over internet to some secret site whose job it is to collect them and use them for evil means?

Comment: How do you know that any app that you install isn't saying in you, watching what you type, and generally misbehaving?

Answer (score 7):

You don't.

However you can put in some basic controls, such as disallowing all outbound traffic, or analysing all outbound traffic for any nasties.

What the use of applications like these boils down to is trust, assurance or confidence. You use an operating system, right? How do you know it isn't doing this? (Actually, you probably know it is doing something like this, if you use Windows or iOS, or Android, or various others)

So, at one extreme, you can avoid all computers, and hide your face, and only use cash etc. or you can use the things that make modern life comfortable and accept there is an element of risk, but try and learn what risks are more likely and worry about them.

Comment: Aww, no mention of packet sniffing? I mean, there's a really fair and valid point here, but there's also ways you can be reasonably confident whether something is/isn't phoning home on a regular basis. Just need the right tools.

Comment: I posit that this is two contradictory answers. You either trust the app or you don't. If you want to make sure an app isn't phoning home, don't start from a position of trust—actively prevent it from phoning home. If, on the other hand, you decide to trust the app, you'd then consider it unnecessary to block its outbound traffic.

Comment: @MathieuK. You're missing "trust but verify" - which is effectively what the OP is looking for, I think.

Comment: There you go @iszi

Comment: @Iszi, I thought about "trust but verify", but it sounded to me like this answer is saying "You can't know. I mean, you could verify, but to a certain extent you've just got to trust it's doing what it says it is." I realize we can list at least three options (mistrust, total trust, and trust-but-verify), but it still sounds to me like this answer says both "just trust it" and "use a firewall", which to me sound like different possible approaches.

Answer (score 2):

It's open-source software, which means you can **download the source and examine it for yourself**. Then, to be sure that the binary is faithful to the source code you're looking at, build it from source (with a known good compiler on a known good system, etc.).

At this writing, source code is available from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%202.x/2.30/KeePass-2.30-Source.zip/

and

http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%201.x/1.29/KeePass-1.29-Src.zip/
,

per the KeePass site (currently http://keepass.info/download.html ). Naturally, check the KeePass site for the latest version.

Comment: I think what a lot of people do is assume that well-known and widely-used open-source software has already had its source code examined by trustworthy and knowledgeable people, and that it's thus non-malicious, does what it says on the tin, and implements reasonable security. I suspect these assumptions are not always warranted, and I'm not suggesting that operating under them is a good security practice. I certainly do it. I'm a beginning programmer, and I hope one day to be knowledgeable enough to make my own assessments based on source code.